# Pandas Dataframe Yahoo Finance Checking if Volume Meets Criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The program below imports thousands of stock tickers from a .CSV file to a list and passes the tickers as a parameter to a function which pulls the 'Adjusted Close' column of that particular stock and sets the ticket as the column name. This was I have one dataframe containing the thousands of stocks and can obtain the adjusted close just by using df['EnterTickerNameHere']. The data from yahoo contains a 'Volume' field which I would like to only add a stock to my df if the volume is greater than 100,000. I am not sure how to do this while keeping my dataframe in the same format it is now. Thank you for reading!

```
import pandas as pd
pd.core.common.is_list_like = pd.api.types.is_list_like
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import datetime
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf
yf.pdr_override()
import time

def getTickers():
    today = str(datetime.date.today())
    fourty_days_prior = str(datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=40))

    # import the tickers from csv to a python list
    tickers = pd.read_csv('tickers.csv', sep='\n',dtype={'Tickers' : str})
    tickers = tickers.Tickers.tolist()

    data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(tickers, start= fourty_days_prior, end=today)['Adj Close']
```

Comment: could you add a small snippet(20 lines or so) of your example input df, and then post an expected output? It will give us a better picture of how we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to download all that data twice.

1) Download the latest volume for each ticker (just 1 day of data required)

2) Apply the condition to this Series to update your ticker list

3) Download the Adj. Close for this reduced ticker list

```
def getTickers(min_volume=100000):
    today = str(datetime.date.today())
    fourty_days_prior = str(datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=40))

    # import the tickers from csv to a python list
    tickers = pd.read_csv('tickers.csv', sep='\n',dtype={'Tickers' : str})
    tickers = tickers.Tickers.tolist()

    # first import the latest volumes and apply your condition
    volumes = pdr.get_data_yahoo(tickers, start=today, end=today)['Volume'].T
    filtered_tickers = volumes[volumes.iloc[:,0] > min_volume].index.tolist()

    data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(filtered_tickers, start= fourty_days_prior, end=today)['Adj Close']
    return data
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you. Is the .T a pandas related function to return the last item of the tail?

Comment: @delhics yes  .T is a pandas method that transposes a dataframe. Just makes the tickers easier to index

Answer (score 0):

first load the ['Adj Close'] in a df:

```
data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(tickers, start= fourty_days_prior, end=today)['Adj Close']
```

Now create a seperate df for the volumes:

```
volume = pdr.get_data_yahoo(tickers, start= fourty_days_prior, end=today)['Volume']
```

(assuming this gets the volumes in a df with column name 'Volume')

Now you can do:

```
data['volume'] = [value if value > 100000 else 0 for value in volume['Volume']
```

(you can use None if you don't want the zero's)

Now you have a volume column in your df which only contains the volume value if it was > 100000

Comment: Thanks Gijs. I appreciate your answer. I was hoping for a solution that wouldn't have to download the data for the 10,000 stocks twice from yahoo data but I think this may be the simplest solution now that the yahoo API is deprecated.

Comment: Can you not download both columns at once with something like [[‘adj close’, ‘volume’]]? Then you can change the volumes afterwards with the same list comprehension as above.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot put more than one column name in the list. Thanks for your time Gijs I will pull all columns and drop them later as this will be the fastes method

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer but I now realize I misread your question. You only want tickers with volume > 100,000 in your df in the first place.

So fetch the tickers with both columns. Then just put a mask on the output df:

data = data[data['volume'] > 100000]

If required you can drop the volume column afterwards with:

data.drop(columns=['volume'])

Comment: You beat me on the comment. I guess you know what you need to do :)